# XHTML unique identifier

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm learning `XHTML` from this book, what they mean by unique identifier:

Here is the image from the book:

[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny here, but it is something that identifies something uniquely. In other words, nothing else will be identified in the same fashion. E.g. a unique primary key on a database table uniquely identifies a specific row in the table. So, that could be called a unique identifier. There are many types of unique identifier though, such as [GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a Unique Identifier is a number or other code that refers to only one thing.  Your phone number is a unique identifier to your phone, similar to your house's address, and your own social security number.

Comment: thanks for replying , i've wanted to give you a good reputation but i can't because am beginner in this site

Comment: Thanks.  You should still be able to mark my answer as the correct answer.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

A unique identifier (UID) is a numeric or alphanumeric string that is associated with a single entity within a given system. UIDs make it possible to address that entity or element, so that it can be accessed and interacted with.